# Why is the last li item appearing outside of the parent container?

Tags: html, css

The last li item in my navigation is appearing outside of its parent. I want it to stay inside the parent container and also have 1em margin to the right (the same spacing as the logo, but opposite).

I've tried placing width: 100% on the menu and ul classes.

```css
*,*:before,*:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }

body {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 30px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #f8f7f3;
}

.body-wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: box;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.83rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li:not(:first-child){
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body-wrap">
    <header class="header">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home-link"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.nicolefenton.com/_/images/dec/circle-menu.svg" height="12" width="12" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Speaking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want the last li item (projects) to have 1em padding to the right of the off-white color. Basically the same spacing as the logo, but opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Because your li has position `absolute` with body tag and body has a border 30px.

You can set right for li to reduce space at right with body.

```
li {
      flex-grow: 1;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;  
      right: 18px;
    }
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }

body {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 30px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #f8f7f3;
}

.body-wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: box;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.83rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li:not(:first-child){
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
  right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body-wrap">
    <header class="header">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home-link"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.nicolefenton.com/_/images/dec/circle-menu.svg" height="12" width="12" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Speaking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```